# SSIS One package VS Many packages To load Excel Files

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I want to accomplish a project, 
I have different DB (same server) for each of my customers.
I have to load an excel file (7 sheets) every month. (Every new month I get new excel file for each customer)
The table in db's are similar to the table in excel sheets by name and columns.

What is the best way to do this kind of project? 
Do I have to create package for each customer  or it's possible to do that with one package for all of the customers (for now,  the table names , columns and number are the same for all of my customers but it can be changed if necessary in the future )

I think the better way is to make for each customer his own package with his own connection for the db.

But do I have to make every time new connection to new excel file that I got or is any other way?

I will pinpoint my project, I have for each customer a DB with 7 tables (all in the same server) and every month I get new excel file CustmoerName_MonthName.xls with 7 sheets (for now, maybe in the future and it can be more tables for one or more customers) If I'm going to use one package how does it will work if the excel file name change everytime And I have different path of the excel files for each customer? Also when I load a excel file its need to be recognize witch customer it is and load it to his own db I don’t get the excel files from the customer in the same day or week for one customer it can be at the beginning of the month and other at the end of the month, I execute the package not in normal schedule like once a week or so.

Comment: I would just make one package, if the only difference is the Database used for each customer, and the name/location of the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions,

1. Create a master table containing the details of the customers and the tables the excel sheet makes for each of them.

2. Create one single package

3. Create a dynamic connection string that takes up the db name and/or server_ip

4. For each customer, take a for-each loop and load the excel sheets accordingly.
This way even if the table names or db changes you will have to change that in the master table and nowhere else.
I hope this helps. :)